# Microsoft Teams Manifest isFullScreen does it works in local debug?

Tags: microsoft-teams, manifest

I'm trying to create a Teams app with the `isFullScreen` property enabled.

However, I don't see any difference in local debug.

Technically, it says in the official documentation that this property only works when the app is published to an organization.

When I add my application in debug is it considered published in the organization or will this property only work if the application is actually submitted and published to an organization and not in local debug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App package must be published in the organization app catalog. Code can be running in local debug or azure.